# using react-awesome-query-builder npm package in next.js Unable to add multiple fields as shown in demo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, query-builder

**I am trying to make a same query builder as the demo using the docs provided ... after adding more fields in the config I get new options in the dropdown .. and to create more fields used multiple Builder components and even tried different config files for each of them .. but they all change simultaneously. How can I create more fields and also have handlers for them**

Link to package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-query-builder
Link to the demo https://ukrbublik.github.io/react-awesome-query-builder/

what am I doing wrong ... How can I add more sections..  here is my component with the config file.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Query, Builder, BasicConfig, Utils as QbUtils} from 'react-awesome-query-builder';
//import AntdConfig from 'react-awesome-query-builder/lib/config/antd/index';
//import loadedInitValue from "./init_value";

const InitialConfig = BasicConfig; // or BasicConfig

// You need to provide your own config. See below 'Config format'
let config = {
  ...InitialConfig,
  fields: {
    qty: {
        label: 'Qty',
        type: 'number',
        fieldSettings: {
            min: 0,
        },
        valueSources: ['value'],
        preferWidgets: ['number'],
    },
    price: {
        label: 'Price',
        type: 'number',
        valueSources: ['value'],
        fieldSettings: {
            min: 10,
            max: 100,
        },
        preferWidgets: ['slider', 'rangeslider'],
    },
    color: {
        label: 'Color',
        type: 'select',
        valueSources: ['value'],
        fieldSettings: {
          listValues: [
            { value: 'yellow', title: 'Yellow' },
            { value: 'green', title: 'Green' },
            { value: 'orange', title: 'Orange' }
          ],
        }
    },
    is_promotion: {
        label: 'Promo?',
        type: 'boolean',
        operators: ['equal'],
        valueSources: ['value'],
    },
    }
  },
};

const queryValue = {"id": QbUtils.uuid(), "type": "group"};

class QueryBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    tree: QbUtils.checkTree(QbUtils.loadTree(queryValue), config),
    config: config
  };
  
  render = () => (
    <div>
      <Query
          {...config} 
          value={this.state.tree}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          renderBuilder={this.renderBuilder}
      />
      {this.renderResult(this.state)}
    </div>
  )  

    renderBuilder = (props) => (
      <div className="query-builder-container" style={{padding: '10px'}}>
        <div className="query-builder qb-lite">
            <Builder {...props} className="my-4" />
            <Builder {...props} className="my-4" />
            <Builder {...props} className="my-4" />
        </div>
      </div>
    )

    renderResult = ({tree: immutableTree, config}) => (
      <div className="query-builder-result">
          <div>Query string: <pre>{JSON.stringify(QbUtils.queryString(immutableTree, config))}</pre></div>
          <div>MongoDb query: <pre>{JSON.stringify(QbUtils.mongodbFormat(immutableTree, config))}</pre></div>
    )
    
    onChange = (immutableTree, config, idx) => {
      // Tip: for better performance you can apply `throttle` - see `examples/demo`
      this.setState({tree: immutableTree, config: config});
      const jsonTree = QbUtils.getTree(immutableTree);
      console.log(jsonTree);
      // `jsonTree` can be saved to backend, and later loaded to `queryValue`
    }
}

export default QueryBuilder;
```

Comment: its too much code with no purpose in your question. point out the error, and where you are falling behind.

Comment: I am trying to have more sections .. but I think a single onClick won't work for all .. I used 3 Builder components for 3 sections but they all change when 1 is changed

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your fields config

```
 results: {
            label: "Results",
            type: "!group",
            subfields: {
                product: {
                    type: "select",
                    fieldSettings: {
                        listValues: ["abc", "def", "xyz"],
                    },
                    valueSources: ["value"],
                },
                score: {
                    type: "number",
                    fieldSettings: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                    },
                    valueSources: ["value"],
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the config and init_value files ... the fields were not properly mapped ... you need to use same name, type etc in the init_value file for the fields you define in config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).